# Unexpected identifier for object Java (Processing)

Tags: java, processing

I was writing code on this chromebook, which I wanted to code in the Processing enviroment, so I searched online for a online Processing, and I got open processing. I get the Unexpected Identifier error on line 1.

```js
Bird bird;

function setup() {
 createCanvas(600, 1000);
 background(0);
 
 bird = new Bird();
}

function draw() {
 bird.show();
}
```

Comment: How do you expect Bird to be defined?  I assume that's your own object.

Comment: Ha!  I didn't look at the tags.  YES, as others say, you should start by being sure you know what language you're using.  If you do know that you're using Javascript, please change the Java tag on your question to Javascript, and then provide a more complete example.  What is **Bird**?  Where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two Processing environments: Processing (which is based on java) and p5.js (which is based on javascript). They are not interchangeable so you need to make sure you know which you're using, and that any examples you're reading are for the corresponding version.

Since you mentioned OpenProcessing and your functions are defined with the `function` keyword, I assume you're using p5.js. In that case, the problem is that javascript is not a typed language, so you don't put the type of the variable before it. Changing

```
Bird bird;
```

to

```
var bird;
```

removes the Unexpected Identifier error, but you'll still have an error on line 7 where you try to do

```
bird = new Bird();
```

without defining what a `Bird` is. Hope that helps! Let me know if you have any other problems.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that p5.js was javascript. I guess I was coding in javascript the whole time.